# Unexpected behavior in Pandas indexing with .loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame, called data, that has datetime indices. When I attempt to index the data by multiple datetimes, an error is raised. Specifically, the code looks like this:

```
times = data.index.values
data.loc[times]
```

which raises the error

```
"None of [DatetimeIndex([       '1997-01-10 06:53:36', '1997-01-10 06:53:36.100000',\n               '1997-01-10 06:53:36.200000', '1997-01-10 06:53:36.300000',\n               '1997-01-10 06:53:36.400000', '1997-01-10 06:53:36.500000',\n               '1997-01-10 06:53:36.600000', '1997-01-10 06:53:36.700000',\n               '1997-01-10 06:53:36.800000', '1997-01-10 06:53:36.900000',\n               ...\n                      '1997-01-10 06:58:05', '1997-01-10 06:58:05.100000',\n               '1997-01-10 06:58:05.200000', '1997-01-10 06:58:05.300000',\n               '1997-01-10 06:58:05.400000', '1997-01-10 06:58:05.500000',\n               '1997-01-10 06:58:05.600000', '1997-01-10 06:58:05.700000',\n               '1997-01-10 06:58:05.800000', '1997-01-10 06:58:05.900000'],\n              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Time', length=2700, freq=None)] are in the [index]"
```

I am having trouble reproducing this error with a simple dataframe I've made myself, as this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':[1,2,3]} , index =[np.datetime64('1997-01-10T06:53:36.000000000'),np.datetime64('1997-01-10T06:53:36.100000000'),np.datetime64('1997-01-10T06:53:36.100000000')] )
times = df.index.values
df.loc[times]
```

just returns the dataframe df.

Additionally,

```
times = data.index
data.loc[times]
```

does return the dataframe data, and looping through the times like so:

```
times = data.index.values
for time in times:
    print(data.loc[time])
```

does not produce the error.

UPDATE

I've found the source of the error, the times I was attempting to index by did not have timezone info, and the times in the dataframe did. So this:

```
times = data.index.values
time_tz = pd.DatetimeIndex(times,name='Time',tz=pytz.utc)
data.loc[time_tz]
```

works as I would have expected.

The error only occurs if I try to index by more than one timezone-free datetime, so now my question is why does

```
times = data.index.values
for time in times:
    print(data.loc[time])
```

not raise an error?

Comment: _I am having trouble reproducing this error with a simple dataframe I've made myself, as this:_ Do you have a slightly larger example that could reproduce the issue? Is the `.values()` even necessary, would `data.index` work?

Comment: The error came up when I was trying to index by more than one time that resulted from a different bit of code, so while data.index does work, it's not the source of the problem I was having.